# Check if user input is in array

Tags: vb.net

I have a array: Dim checkmethods() = ["method1", "method2", "method3]

However, when I try; `If input = checkmethods then`
Which shows a error in my console.

> Error 6   Overload resolution failed because no accessible '=' can be
> called with these arguments: 'Public Shared Operator =(a As String, b
> As String) As Boolean': Value of type '1-dimensional array of String'
> cannot be converted to 'String'.  C:\Users\crimb\Desktop\VB
> Projects\Weeb Hub\Weeb NET\Module1.vb 301 12  Weeb NET

Comment: What is input?  Users can't input array's directly, they can input delimited strings for example that you would convert to arrays

Comment: Firstly, the "code" you posted couldn't possibly compile. ALWAYS show us the actual code that causes the issue. Sometimes we can work out what the actual code would be and sometimes we can't, but we shouldn't have to anyway.

Comment: As for the issue, how could the user input equal the array? Look at your own title. You want to know whether the input is in the array. Have you searched the web to find out how to check whether a value is in an array? I suspect that that is something that would be easy to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to identify if something is present in an array, you have to use the index of the array.

```
for i = 0 to 2 
    if checkmethods(i) = input then
        'add your output here
    end if 
next
```

Hope this is helpful :)